# .gitignore does't ignore files properly

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a github repository with a few .c, .s, .txt files, a Makefile and a .vscode and two .dSYM directories which have been created during debugging. I want to ignore these last three files. My .gitignore is the following:

```
*.vscode
*.dSYM
```

Both .dSYM files have a folder named Contents; my problem is that one (and only one!) of these folders is not ignored. Why does this happen? How can I solve this?

[Link](https://github.com/isabelfdez/libasm.git) to my repository

Comment: Have you added to the repository previously?

Comment: The .gitignore won't ignore (or remove) files that have already been added/commited to the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a forward slash if you want git to ignore all the files inside the directory.

```
/libasm.dSYM
```

**UPDATE**

And if you already git added some folders/files, their changes will still be tracked. To remove those files from your repository (but not from your file system) use `git rm --cached` on them.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

Then commit your changes:

```
git commit -m "Untrack files in .gitignore"
```

Comment: Done it, still not working :(

Comment: @fdez Check my updated answer